# Pushing a double array element to an array jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this array:

```
var array = {
item: 'value',
subArray: []
}
```

I would like to use a `$.each` function to loop through some data and push `key:value` values into the `subArray`. **After pushing the array should look like this**:

```
var array = {
item: 'value',
subArray: [item: 'value', item: 'anothervalue', ...]
}
```

I'm currently using this inside my `$.each` loop:

```
$('class').each(function() {
    array.subArray.push({ 'item': $(this).html() });
});
```

However, the current result is this:

```
var array = {
item: 'value',
subArray: [{item: 'value'}, {item: 'anothervalue'}, ...]
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, you have an object not an array. Secondly, javascript does not have associative arrays. The closest you can get is an array of objects, which is what your final example is.

Answer (score 2):

Your desired result of `subArray: [item: 'value', item: 'anothervalue', ...]` is invalid. Arrays are **not** key/val pairs - that's an object. The result you are getting is the actual result you want.

```
[{item: 'value'}, {item: 'anothervalue'}, ...]
```

Is a perfectly valid array of objects. To add to the confusion of your code above:

```
var array = {
    item: 'value',
    subArray: []
}
```

The above is not an array - it's an object with two properties (`item`, and `subArray`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that later on in the function I convert my `array` to JSON, and the JSON should look like this: `subArray{"item": "value", "item": "anothervalue"}` - any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: @Frank that JSON structure is completely invalid as you have duplicate `item` keys within it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Thanks for letting me know, I'll have to change a few things :)

Comment: @Frank -- Why? You're converting to something that can't be converted to anything else - as it's invalid.